# Is overpressure really an appropriate criteria for blast damage?

Tags: structural-engineering, nuclear-engineering

So, I went on Nukemap, and they gave me the following values for blast effects.

1 psi (7 kPa): windows break
5 psi (34 kPa): most residential buildings collapse

These numbers are way too high. 1 psi corresponds to 237mph (381 km/h, 66 m/s) at sea level. This is enough to destroy every single building.

What this tells me is that there is some other factor at play. Specifically, the blast wave is of such a short duration that no building has sufficient time to react. In effect, the blast wave is an impact force, not a wind or pressure force. Therefore, it would seem more appropriate to quantify destructive potential in impulse, rather than pressure.
L The implications of this error are serious, since for a given overpressure, a larger blast produces greater impulse. Hence Nukemap and all other calculations that use the overpressure to determine destruction are wildly wrong.

Comment: Is that 237mph a constant? or only within a specified distance of the blast origin?

Comment: After some distance, being hit by blast debris or 'wind' is almost impossible, and there are just 2 things that can reach you; pressure waves and radio waves. So pressure is actually quite important parameter.

Comment: @TomášLétal no, pressure and wind are inseparable parts of the blast wave. Pressure cannot change without density change, and density cannot change without air movement.

Comment: @Abdullah You are right some air movement is required, but I would not call that wind. A good example of pressure wave is sound. When you hear a sound, do you also sense wind?

Comment: @TomášLétal no, because the pressure is quite low, 2Pa.at 100Db

Comment: @Abdullah Ok, so what would be the wind speed and orientation during a 5Pa sound?

Comment: In this context, if you're talking about "pressure" you have to specify some frame of refrence.....  commonly "outside the building" vs "inside the building" for example. Alternatively, in the direction of the shockwave's movement. Then consider the forces generated over the area of windows, or walls . . . .

Comment: Overpressure isn't dynamic pressure. Overpressure is the change in pressure across the shock front. The velocities in front and behind the shock front are the same. A shock driven by a jet of fluid will normally have greater dynamic pressure in the jet than it's associated shock overpressure. Of course, things get complicated when the shock and jet impact an object. Scale is very important. Maximum blast effect occurs when the overpressure has a rise distance about the same as the object's size. Blast energy runs about as the cube of rise distance normal to the shock at constant overpressure.

Comment: @PhilSweet I don't know about shockwaves, but for ordinary waves, the dynamic pressure is equal to the static overpressure.

Comment: @TomášLétal a speaker produces both positive and negative air pressures to generate sound

Comment: @jsotola I know, I was just trying to show Abdullah, that pressure wave is not wind.

Comment: @TomášLétal also I forgot to mention. The audible frequencies are so high that we can't resolve the back and forth wind.

Comment: @TomášLétal 15m/s peak alternating to and fro at no more than 0.02s intervals

Comment: How is that 237mph calculated?  Is it the speed at which the dynamic pressure is 1psi, or is it the velocity change on going 1psi up the shock Hugoniot?

Comment: @DanielHatton I simply used the dynamic pressure equation

Comment: @Abdullah There might be some issue with this "*for a given overpressure, a larger blast produces greater impulse*". What would be the range of blast magnitudes which could actually be produced for a given overpressure? Also, how would you measure blast magnitude? [Here for example](https://www.atomicarchive.com/science/effects/overpressure.html), it is measured using overpressure.

Comment: @TomášLétal all blast magnitudes can produce a given overpressure, just at different radii

Comment: 237mph might not knock down a building if the "wind" only lasts for a few milliseconds. Hence it is not accurate to equate blast pressure and windspeed.

Comment: Why do you not use metric units, so people could understand your post without converting it first?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 because most (good) engineers can deal with many units - there are 4 for temperature for a start.

Comment: @SolarMike Good engineers don't use non-metric units. They are a pain and we should get rid of them as soon as possible. Use metric units.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Real engineers are competent in many sets of units - if you are explaining that you are not competent in other units then that's fine.

Comment: @SolarMike Maybe, but I think to devise a coherent system of units that includes both miles per hour and pounds' force per square inch, you'd have to invent an awful lot of new names.

Comment: @SolarMike Non-metric units are objectivity worse than metric units (well, except the Planck units, but we don't talk about them right now). Only stupid people choose them over metric units. I know enough about this "units" (probably more than you) that i know we should not use them. I used "" for units because they are not really units. For example a inch can vary from about 2 cm to 3+1/3 cm, and yes, a inch of 3+1/3 cm is still used today (mainly Taiwan).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 " objectivity " ? or objectively? Those units have been around for a long time and some of us are capable in both sets of units even if you are not. As many people in many countries are still using them, your opinion won't get them to change.

Comment: Both of you play nicely or I'll have to re-express the question entirely in dimensionless numbers.

Comment: @DanielHatton Will you prefer Rayleigh or Buckingham? :)

Comment: @SolarMike The Rayleigh method is just a special case of the Buckingham pi theorem anyway.  But then, you knew that.

Comment: @SolarMike This are not just 2 sets of units, the ancient units are incompatible with themself and units with the same name often have different, incompatible definitions. There is not just one inch and one pound, there are a multitude of different inches with different lengths and a few 100 different pounds. For today, it does not matter what we used 1000 years ago.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but I think a key part of the answer will be this: in order for the **steady** flow energy equation to apply, and provide convertibility between static pressure, dynamic pressure, and velocity, one has to rig things so that the flow is steady, i.e. one has to work in the rest frame of the shock.  Therefore, whatever velocity one calculates that way will be a velocity _relative to the shock front_.  Transforming back into the rest frame of the building will make the air velocity behind the shock much smaller (and flip its direction).

Comment: "The implications of this error are serious" sort of, but I really don't think it's going to change the leading-order conclusion that the consequences of detonating a nuclear bomb in an urban area will be very bad and one should avoid it at all costs.